# function render elements letters by letters not as string

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

goal of the script:

parse log files => say operation on host was successfull or failed depending on some text in log file => extract Hostnames and write them to a CSV file

Problem:

When i try to write datas in the csv file, it outputs me only the last member of list and shows it a letter by line

```py
def parselogfiles(directory):
    for f in os.listdir(directory):
        if f.endswith(".log"):
            filepath = os.path.join(directory,f)
            if os.stat(filepath).st_mtime > now - 1 * 86400:
                with open (filepath, mode="rt", encoding="utf-8") as logfile:
                    f2 = logfile.read()
                    if success in f2:
                        hostname = re.findall(r'\w{1,5}\-\d{1,2}', f2)
                        accesses = successm+hostname[0]
                    elif failure in f2:
                        hostname = re.findall(r'\w{1,5}\-\d{1,2}', f2)
                        accesses = failmessage+hostname[0]
                print(accesses)
    return (accesses)

with open(filename, mode='a', newline='') as lg:
    writer = csv.writer(lg, dialect='excel')
    for l in parselogfiles(logdir):
        print (l)
        writer.writerow([l])

print("write succeeded")
```

What i want to get is:

SUCCESS: HOSTNAME-01

SUCCESS: HOSTNAME-02

FAILURE: HOSTNAME-03

what I get is:

F

A

I

L

U

R

E

:

H

O

S

T

N

A

M

E

-

0

3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accesses`is a string. You reset `accesses` inside every iteration of the `for` Loop by doing `accesses = ...`, so in the end, `return accesses` will only return the result string for the last file that was processed. Now,

```
for l in parselogfiles(logdir):
    print (l)
    writer.writerow([l])
```

will iterate over all individual characters of that string, thus leading to the output you're getting.

One way to achieve what you want is to use a list instead, and put the result strings of all files inside that list. It's just some small changes to your code:

```
def parselogfiles(directory):
    accesses = []  # is now an empty list
    for f in os.listdir(directory):
        if f.endswith(".log"):
            filepath = os.path.join(directory,f)
            if os.stat(filepath).st_mtime > now - 1 * 86400:
                with open (filepath, mode="rt", encoding="utf-8") as logfile:
                    f2 = logfile.read()
                    if success in f2:
                        hostname = re.findall(r'\w{1,5}\-\d{1,2}', f2)
                        accesses.append(successm+hostname[0])  # saves the result to the list
                    elif failure in f2:
                        hostname = re.findall(r'\w{1,5}\-\d{1,2}', f2)
                        accesses.append(failmessage+hostname[0])
                print(accesses)  # will print the list once after every file
    return (accesses)  # returns the list after all files have been processed

with open(filename, mode='a', newline='') as lg:
    writer = csv.writer(lg, dialect='excel')
    for l in parselogfiles(logdir):  # now will print elements of the list instead of characters in the string
        print (l + '\n')
        writer.writerow([l])

print("write succeeded")
```

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation and the solution